# SSH execute remote command infacmd.sh is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, devops, informatica

```
sshpass -p "xxx" ssh -t -t abc@usllpz107.net.com 'cd /opt/tools/informatica/ids/Informatica/10.2.0/isp/bin;infacmd.sh oie importObjects -dn Domain_IDS_Dev -un abc -pd "xxx" -rs MRS_IDS_DEV -sdn LDAP_NP -fp /opt/tools/informatica/ids/Informatica/10.2.0/tomcat/bin/source/mapping_import.xml -cp /opt/tools/informatica/ids/Informatica/10.2.0/tomcat/bin/source/import_control_file.xml'| tee -a logfile.log
```

I am running the above command from container in Buildspec as well as tested in ec2 instance , Command is failing with error: `sh: infacmd.sh: command not found`

But When i tried only command `sshpass -p "xxx" ssh -t -t abc@usllpz107.net.com` and executed other command manually in ec2 then command is working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file exists at the path.
Make sure you have access to the file.
Make sure the file is executable or change the command to

> ; /bin/bash infacmd.sh ...

Comment: Verified the Access Level and Tried with /bin/bash ... Command is getting excecuted in Ubuntu EC2 Instance , But in Buildspec.yml File , redirected output 'cat logfile.log' is not displaying anything!

Comment: Can we do sshpass from Buildspec.yml file?